# Strange NullpointerException when trying to retrieve LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-linearlayout

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but perhaps I'm making an obvious mistake;
I have a LinearLayout defined in my main.xml, with an id "@+id/imageListContainer". There is nothing else in my main.xml, and the LinearLayout is completely plain (As eclipse inserts it for you from the GUI editor).

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imageListContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
```

I then want to populate the LinearLayout dynamically, using this code:

```
LinearLayout imageContainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.imageListContainer);
```

from withhin the applications onCreate() callback function.

This used to work fine. However, as I started to add bits and pieces of code here and there (mainly in other activities), at some point it stopped working, and now I consistently get returned a nullpointer by findViewById(). I tried re-generating R.java, renaming the LinearLayout (to make sure I had control from where it was accessed; but it's only accessed from this one single place). I tried putting the code into onStart() instead, thinking that onCreate might run too early, creating a race-condition, but no luck with that either. I also made sure that the LinearLayout is indeed called "imageListContainer", which it is (otherwise the generated R.java would be wrong and javac would complain anyway) and that there is no duplicate "imageListContainer" object anywhere.

I'm pretty much lost as to what the cause of this could be, so I'd appreciate any suggestions or guesses.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  327): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime(  327): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.company.PictureListView/com.company.PictureListView.PictureListView.PictureListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(  327):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
E/AndroidRuntime(  327):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
E/AndroidRuntime(  327):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
E/AndroidRuntime(  327):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
E/AndroidRuntime(  327):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  327):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  327):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
E/AndroidRuntime(  327):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  327):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(  327):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
E/AndroidRuntime(  327):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
E/AndroidRuntime(  327):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  327): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(  327):        at com.company.PictureListView.PictureListActivity.updateMainActivityScreen(PictureListActivity.java:50)
E/AndroidRuntime(  327):        at com.company.PictureListPictureListActivity.onCreate(PictureListActivity.java:38)
E/AndroidRuntime(  327):        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime(  327):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
```

**PS:** I forgot to mention, I also called setContentView(R.layout.main), so that's not the problem either.

**PSS:** I tried adding a button to the GUI instead, and then calling the code containing the findViewById() inside the callback for that button, and that works! This leads me back to the idea that there might be some race-condition going on.

Comment: Did you call setContentView(R.layout.main) ? If not you have to inflate the xml layout with the LayoutInflater

Comment: Have you called ´setContentView` in the activity?

Comment: Is that all you got in main.xml? You might be missing `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` from the first line and `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` from the LinearLayout if that is the case. If not, show us your `onCreate` and `updateMainActivityScreen`.

Comment: @Jarno Argillander I have both of those, so unfortunately, no.

Comment: @slukian Unfortunately I'm not in a position to disclose the whole code (unfortunate situation, I realize -- especially as the problem seems to arise through interference with some other piece of code) but the code where the exception is thrown is literally just the line after the line I provided, where I subsequently try to call a method on the object I retrieved using findViewById

Comment: Have you tried clean project + refresh project + build project + run again?

Comment: @Jarno Argillander I've tried refreshing the project, restarting eclipse, restarting the android emulator. I've not yet tried to create a new clean project, but if nothing else works out, I guess that's what I'll have to do.

Comment: Clean project = select your project, then Project menu -> Clean...

Comment: Do you have an inner class in your activity? I read the exception trace carefully: first `com.company.PictureListPictureListActivity.onCreate` then `com.company.PictureListView.PictureListActivity.updateMainActivityScreen` --> seems to me `findViewById` is called in a different object. Try moving the `findViewByID` into the `onCreate` and check if it works there.

Comment: @Jarno Argillander fascinating that seems to have solved the problem!

Comment: I'll post that as an answer then :)

Comment: @Jarno Argillander there was an inner class, but I deleted it in an attempt to simplify what's going on. Perhaps a generated .class file from it was still lingering on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was the answer from the comments of the question:

> Do you have an inner class in your activity? I read the exception
>   trace carefully: first
>   **com.company.PictureListPictureListActivity.onCreate** then
>   **com.company.PictureListView.PictureListActivity.updateMainActivityScreen**
>   --> seems to me findViewById is called in a different object. Try moving the findViewByID into the onCreate and check if it works there.

It seems there was an inner class at some point of development, which was later removed. Somehow project files were not updated appropriately. Cleaning the project, refreshing file system contents, and re-building the project should make things right again.

Comment: To clarify, the problem went away after I told eclipse to clean the project as you suggested. I'm not sure what exactly the problem was, but it might've been a .class file from the nested class lingering on. I'll investigate the issue closer later on, for now I'm happy to be back on track. Thanks for your time, and have all my upvotes.

Comment: Ok, good :) I've noticed that whenever resources are modified there's a big chance something goes wrong. I always clean + refresh + build project after modifying resources. Never had issues since adopting this fashion.